# How to use linting indent rule in tsx?

Tags: reactjs, tslint

I use `TypeScript` and `React TSX`. For linting, I use `tslint` and `tslint-react`. How to write the rule for indent in `TSX`.

```
 <ModalLink title={linkText} className={styles.modalLink} component={createTermsLink(linkText)}>
          // want to get  2 spaces indent error. vvv  
          <Content contentKey={contentKey} />
  </ModalLink>
```